# Call a function pointer in a function C++

Tags: c++, pointers

In main function I calls the Choice function. The goal is to choose the sort type with the order of increase or decrease. 
I calls Choice to receive the address of two IsBigger and Interchange functions.
Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void Swap(T *a, T *b)
{
    T temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

template <class T>
void Interchange(T a[], int n, bool(*Cmp)(T, T))
{
   for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (Cmp(a[i], a[j]))
                Swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
}

template <class T>
void Insertion(T a[], int n, bool(*Cmp)(T, T))
 {
    int x, j;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        x = a[i]; j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && !Cmp(a[j],x))
        {
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
    a[j + 1] = x;
    }
}

template <class T>
bool IsBigger(T a, T b)
{ 
    return a > b;
}


template <class T>
void Choice(T a[], int n, bool(*Cmp)(T, T), void(*Sort)(T*, int, bool*))
{
Sort(a, n, Cmp);
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 3,4,1,5 };
    Choice<int>(a, 4, &IsBigger, &Interchange);
    return 0;
}
```

In main function, function Choice has error when it calls IsBigger and Interchange. The error is "no instance of function template "Choice" matches the argument list"
I don't know what am I wrong. Please help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: `Choice<int>(a, 4, IsBigger<int>, Interchange<int>);` Actually, `Choice` has wrong signature. It says `Sort` should be a function that takes `bool*` as its third parameter, but calls it passing something other than `bool*`

Comment: You have wrong `Sort` signature in `Choice`: `void(*Sort)(T*, int, bool*)` (check the 3rd arg). If you fix it, it compiles.

Comment: You better make `Cmp` type templated as well then it will not only work with function pointers.